# What is the point of mocking the method of an external library when unit testing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing

What is the point of mocking the method of an external library when unit testing?

Let's say that I have a function that uses XYZ library to get the current user using a given authorization token, and then if it finds the user, it returns a valid AWS policy:

```
export const getUser = async token => {
  const user = await XYZ.getUser(token)
  return {
    // valid policy
    context: user,
  }
}
```

If an invalid token is given, the `getUser` should throw an error.

- What is the point of testing this function if the `XYZ.getUser` is already well tested?
- Why mock the `getUser` instead of using the real one?

Comment: Do you want to know why to mock `getUser` or why to mock `XYZ.getUser`?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to invoke the actual HTTP request for `XYZ.getUser(token)`, due to the following reasons.

1) The objective of unit testing is to test a specific behaviour, and in your very case, it is to test that your `getUser` function actually works.

2) You wouldn't want to make an actual request to the backend, as that would usually mean writing/reading/deleting something from the database. In many cases, it is not a good idea to overcomplicate your unit testing, as such operations should not be tested on the front-end, since you would want to limit and simplify your unit testing to test for a very specific behaviour.

3) Since the main objective is to test the above behaviour, you would want to simplify and limit what you are testing. As such, you will need to understand that unit testing of network requests of `XYZ.getUser(token)` should be done at the server-side, instead of client-side (or front-end).

4) By mocking the response from `XYZ.getUser(token)`, we can simulate multiple scenarios and responses, such as successful responses (Code 200 OK), and other types of errors (business logic errors from the backend, or network errors such as error 400, 500, etc). You can do so by hardcoding the required JSON responses from `XYZ.getUser(token)` on the different types of scenarios you need to test.

Answer (score 0):

this goes back to the definition and usages of unit tests.

Unit tests are supposed to test well defined functionality, for example you might write an algorithm and the functionality of that is very well defined. Then, because you know how it's supposed to function then you would  unit test that.

Unit tests by definition, are not meant to touch any external systems, such as but not limited to files, APIs, databases, anything that requires going outside of the logical unit which is the code you want to test.

There are multiple reasons for that among which is execution speed. Calling an API, or using a third party call, takes a while. That's not necessary a problem when you look at one test, but when you have 500 tests or more then the delays will be important. The main idea is that you are supposed to run your unit tests all the time, very quickly, you get immediate feedback, is anything broken, have I broken something in other parts of the system. In any mature system you will run these tests as part of your CI/CD process and you cannot afford to wait too long for them to finish. no, they need to run in seconds, which is why you have the rules of what they should or should not touch.

You mock external things, to improve execution speed and eliminate third party issues as you really only want to test your own code.

What if you call a third party API and they are down for maintenance? Does that mean you can't test your code because of them?

Now, on the topic of mocking, do not abuse it too much, if you code in a functional way then you can eliminate the need for a lot of mocking. Instead of passing or har-coding dependencies, pass data. This makes it very easy to alter the input data without mocking much. You test the system as a while using integration / e2e tests, this gives you the certainty that your dependencies are resolved correctly.